# Java: While loop in Byte Stream

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

Can someone explain why the loop is checking if condition is different than -1?

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(c);
}
```

Comment: Because `c` will be -1 when the end of the stream is reached. Read the documentation for `InputStream.read`. (Having said that, this is an inefficient way of copying an InputStream to an OutputStream...)

Comment: This way was described in [Oracle The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html) Thanks anyway for the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#read()

When there is no more bytes to read, the read method returns -1

Comment: More specifically, the -1 means EOF (end of file)

Answer (score 3):

Loops in Java require `boolean` clause in the condition part.

`c = in.read()` evaluates to a `int` and not a `boolean`. Thus you need to compare it with some value (in your case `-1` to indicate no more bytes to read) which generate `boolean` values as stopping condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
```

The `read` method returns -1 when the end of stream is reached. The condition assigns the return value of `read` to c and checks if `c` is not -1. If it is -1, end of stream is reached, else not.